# Laravel: eager loading both belongsTo and HasMany relationships?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have two models Product and ProductCategory which are related, one product beongs to one product category and one product category can have many products.

Here are my models:

Product:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    public function productcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ProductCategory');
    }
}
```

ProductCategory:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class ProductCategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productcategories';
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->HasMany('App\Models\Product');
    }
}
```

I retrieve all categories with their respective attached products like this:

```
$productCategories = ProductCategory::with('products')->get();
```

This works but I want it so that I can access product category info from the products, this is because I'm using vue to loop throught each category products but I need to access category info from product itself, not just the product_category_id but other fields!

In my component I want to do this:

```
product.productcategory.name
```

But currently I only get access to:

```
product.product_category_id
```

I'd rather not make an ajax call to my API to get this information, how can I get around this?

Comment: Where and how are you using component? The vue component code might help accessing the category name directly from the existing model.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) like this

`$productCategories = ProductCategory::with('products', 'products.productcategory')->get();`

But you should consider re-using the ProductCategory value directly in your vue file.